# Migrate character from Xbox to Playstation

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Can you bring your character over from Xbox Live to the Playstation Network? Just wondering if it's possible via the Rockstar cloud server.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is currently no way to do this.